# How should I post code such that I do not give away too many details about my application's code?

Tags: discussion

When I ask a question on the Internet, I generally post some code to allow others to review it. However, I don't want my posting of code to allow some other guy to discover what kind of app I'm building and help him to develop a copycat application. Is there a generally-accepted rule that would allow me to post code while omitting some details?

Comment: If you've posted enough code for us to tell what you're building, you've posted too much code and you should go back and narrow your example down further.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can:

- Create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code
- If that still looks copy-cattable/gives away too many clues - then generalise variable names/values to remove its specific context of use, but not the functionality or ability for others to grok or assist in answering
- If you're still not happy to post that - then **don't** - you'll have to find somewhere else to get an answer than on the public internet.

Comment: Creating a working example may even help you figure out the solution to your problem, because as you create your example, you're thinking about exactly what you're doing.